# Audio when hover over an image

Tags: jquery, audio, hover

I am trying to play multiple audio files when the viewer hovers over different images, and I do not wish any of the player/bar/function to be shown on the screen, I just want the viewer to hover over the image, and the sound plays, it will finish playing even if the user moved the cursor away. All my images are being placed in apDiv tags

```
$(function(){
    $('#apDiv3').hover(
    function() { $("killyou")[0].play(); },
    function() { $("killyou")[0].pause(); }
    )
});


<audio id="killyou" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="iwilkillyou.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
    <div id="apDiv3">
        <img src="explosion_by_dbszabo1-d3hmssu.png" width="175" height="5">
    </div>
</audio>
```

I got this to work when hovering, it plays the sound, but I cant use it for multiple images, and the sound stops when the mouse is moved away from the image, it's my first time using html and JQuery, anyone can help me out with this? Thank you!

Comment: Please post your complete HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

(edit: re-read your question)

Perhaps:

```
$('.audio-source img').mouseover(function() {
    $('player source').attr('src', $(this).data('file'))
            .parent()[0].play();
});
```

With HTML:

```
<audio hidden id="player" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="default-audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
<div class="audio-source">
    <img data-file="foo.mp3" src="image-1.png"/>
    <img data-file="bar.mp3" src="image-2.png"/>
    <img data-file="baz.mp3" src="image-3.png"/>
</div>
```

I'm currently unable to test that, though.

The jQuery function `.hover(on, off)` binds two functions, one for mouse over, one for mouse off. All you need is mouse on, so you can use the function `.mouseover(function)`.
What the jQuery snippet does is grab the `data-file` attribute from the image you hover over, and apply it to the `src` attribute of the `<source>` tag. Then we grab the parent, which is the `<audio>` tag, and call `play()` on the DOM node.